# Magento 2 Luma grid css

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, css

I just want to use the default Magento 2 Luma theme as a base theme to develop.

But does this theme has some kind of a grid layout.
So that I can easily add 3 blocks of 33% width beside each other.

So some kind of css like grid-3, grid-6 or grid-12? Or something like Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luma is more like a starting point and with magento theme inheritance you can extend this theme and add Twitter Bootstrap in your own theme.

Please refer to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html for more information.